# Round corner full bottom screen for portrait & landscape mode?

Tags: ios, image, uiview, landscape, portrait

I want to add rounded corners image on my UIView, so I made ​​two of my images 12x12px rounded corners.

I want to know how best to add my view taking into account that he must align automatically in portrait and landscape mode in the bottom of the total screen!

This is what I did now, but that does not work:

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


        self.brcLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, result.height-12.0, 12.0, 12.0)];
        self.brcLeft.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brc-left"];
        [self.view addSubview:brcLeft];

        self.brcRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(result.width-12.0, result.height-12, 12.0, 12.0)];
        self.brcRight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brc-right"];
        [self.view addSubview:brcRight];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?? Do you want a rounded corner image? or do you want that the image is always positioned at the bottom of the screen in your app?

Comment: My question is very specific, and the code says it even, no!!?

Yes, the round corners are images and yes we must always set on the bottom of the screen!

Comment: wht actually do u want ?is it u want the view also to have ropund corner so that ur round corner image fits properly?

Answer (score 0):

For setting your views to both orientation at the bottom of the screen do this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation   
{  
     CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.brcLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, screenFrame.size.height - self.brcLeft.frame.size.height , 12.0, 12.0)];

[self.brcRight setFrame:CGRectMake(result.width-12.0, screenFrame.size.height - self.brcRight.frame.size.height , 12.0, 12.0)];
    return YES;

}
```

and for rounded Corners:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

write this in your viewDidLoad

```
self.brcLeft.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
self.brcLeft.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

self.brcRight.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
self.brcRight.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: No sorry, this solution with QuartzCore, i know already! 

I specify that i had two images, one for my lower right corner and one for my lower left corner!

Now, I must just be able to position absolute these images!

Comment: for that you should set the frame of the images in the - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation method. Now since you always want to set them to the bottom of the screen you dont need to check for the orientation in this method. You can simply get the current screen size and set the frame of the image as per your current screen. just subtract the image height from the screen height for setting the Y co-ordinate of the image.

Comment: I have posted it in my answer. Just try it.

Comment: Have you synthesized both the images as properties?? probably do that and it might work.

Comment: Yes, i've synthesized all images !!! Perhaps your setframe in your code is "setFrame" instead , no !!!?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo!! sorry my bad.. I have edited the code now.